# Why did docker container restart?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an application inside a `docker-compose`. On startup, a lot of logging messages are created. When looking at the logs of my `docker-compose` in the morning, I can see those startup messages, but just before that the container was logging production messages.

In the past it happened that the application crashed because of a bug and restarted. Another time there was a memory problem because lots of data was accidently loaded, then there were error messages saying from Go indicating OutOfMemeory errors, then the container restarted.

But from time to time the container restarts without any indication why. How can I find out the reason why it restarts?

Comment: hard to say without any particular details. How is your app logging? How is your restart policy working?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the host, I would suggest using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) to persist the container's entire `/var/log` somewhere on the host. You can look at these log files to discover reasons for shutdown. Check out [this unix.stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278166/422161) for details on how to do that.